# Header background not showing using ::before psuedo element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to make the background of my header opaque without affecting the text.

I've tried a few different things like putting a set width and height, separating the background properties (background-repeat, background-position).

When I include the same background property inside just the header {} css it shows up.

But changing its opacity makes the text opaque as well which I am trying to avoid.

Any suggestions? Thanks so much in advance! Here's the link to the photo (I saved it as a jpeg): https://i2.wp.com/digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/sunset-photography-tips-1.jpg?fit=1500%2C1000&ssl=1

```css
header {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

header::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url('../images/sunset.jpg') no-repeat top center;
    background-size:cover;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <h1> <span class="greeting">Hi,<br/> 
            I'm Tatyana,</span><br/> 
            aspiring front-end developer</h1>
        <button name="contact" type="button" value="text">Contact Me!</button>
    </header>
```

Comment: Your pseudo element does not have any dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why is it doing this?

`position: absolute` will position your `header::before` *relative the first element enclosing it that is given an explicit position*.
In this case, probably defaulting to the `<body>`.

It will also be given whatever the browser thinks it's 'default' size and position should be. I assume the browser will be wrong in these cases and tell it what to do.

## How to fix it?

We just need to give the `<header>` a position, and make sure the psudo-element goes where we want, rather than trusting that the browser will default us to it.

```css
header {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

header::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url('../images/sunset.jpg') no-repeat top center;
    background-size:cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
header {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

header::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url('https://i2.wp.com/digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/sunset-photography-tips-1.jpg?fit=1500%2C1000&ssl=1') no-repeat top center;
    background-size:cover;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    <span class="greeting">Hi,
      <br />
      I'm Tatyana,
    </span>
    <br />
    aspiring front-end developer
  </h1>
  <button name="contact" type="button" value="text">
    Contact Me!
  </button>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   header {
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    header::before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        background: url('https://i2.wp.com/digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/sunset-photography-tips-1.jpg?fit=1500%2C1000&ssl=1') no-repeat top center;
        background-size:cover;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        opacity: 0.75;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0,
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

Hi.Do you want like this?